# Mime type in nginx for dynamic url

Tags: nginx

user upload file and its kept in `file` directory without file extensions

so it looks like file/ID

what i had done,
when user download any file, we have created a rewrite rule for the same which looks like

rewrite ^/file/(.+?)/(.*)$ /file/$1;

http://example.com/file/id/name.mp4 -> http://example.com/file/id

now, the problem i face is nginx is giving content-type (mime) a `application/octet-stream`

Which is not the actual mime type of file, this is because default mime type is application/octet-stream

i also know we can change the same using nginx configuration,

But my question is that can we set mime-type base on the url file extension

Comment: But you got rid of the file extension! Try keeping it.

Comment: I have a somewhat related issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/889301/is-it-possible-to-restrict-download-by-mime-type-content-type-in-nginx and I suspect the answer to both our question is "it's not possible", if nginx doesn't indeed use something like MIME magic to determine file types, instead of just relying on filename endings. If it uses filename endings (extensions) only, then we may be SOL...